# WebMatrix razor C# WebSecurity Logging in but Web.Security.IsAuthenticated not returning right check

Tags: c#, razor, authentication, webmatrix

I have a quick question.  In my code, I have this:

```
if(!(username.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty()))
    {
        if (WebSecurity.UserExists(username) && WebSecurity.GetPasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess(username) > 4 && WebSecurity.GetLastPasswordFailureDate(username).AddSeconds(120) > DateTime.UtcNow) 
        {
            Session["gActionMessage"] = "You're account has been locked due to too many failed login attempts. " +
                                            "Please try again in 2 minutes.";
            Session["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
            Response.Redirect("~/");
            return;
        }

        if(WebSecurity.Login(username, password, false))
        {
            errorMessage = "";
        }
    }

    if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        errorMessage = "You are no longer logged in. Please supply your username and password credentials along with the rest of the form data.";
    }
```

When I attempt to use this code (the check right after the login is actually within an if(IsPost), so that I can check whether the user is still logged in before using the posted data.  When it fails the check "if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)" for the first time, a small section of the page opens up, asking for login information.  Once reentered and re-posted, the check reads the value of "username" and "password" and attempts to re-log them in.  It does just that, however directly after they are supposed to be "logged in" it passes the "if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)" branch and executes its contents. Am I checking the "if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)" to soon? Does the page have to finish loading before a person is actually considered authenticated?

I just can't seem to pinpoint why this is happening and haven't been able to find any help in research either.

Thanks, everyone, for any help!

UPDATE:

I have posted the code that appears below the code above, below:

```
if((Roles.IsUserInRole((WebSecurity.CurrentUserName), "Locked")) || (Roles.IsUserInRole((WebSecurity.CurrentUserName), "AdminLocked")))
    {
        Session["gActionMessage"] = "Your account is locked. ";
        Session["gActionMessage"] += "Please contact an administrator and ask that your account be approved.";
        Session["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
}
}

@RenderPage("~/Shared/HeaderLayout.cshtml")

        <div>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location.href='/IntroPage.cshtml'">Main Page</button></span><span class="heading">Lookup Entry</span><span><button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('searchForm').submit()">Search</button></span></br></br>
            <span style="font-size: 3em; color: #808080;">________________________________________________</span></br></br></br>
        </div>

        <div id="FormHolder">
            <form id="searchForm" class="searchForm" method="post" action="">
        @{
            if (errorMessage != "")
            {
                <div class="errorMessageWrapper"><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: 700;">ERROR:</span><br/>@errorMessage<br/><br/>
                    @if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated && success==false)
                    {
                        <table class="accInterfaceTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                                    <label for="username">Email:</label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="accInterfaceInputCell">
                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br/><br/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br/><br/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table><br/><br/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenLoginSubmit" name="hiddenLoginSubmit" value="" />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Log In" />
                    }
                </div><br/>
            }
        }
                <table class="searchTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Search Field<br/><br/></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Search Condition<br/><br/></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Search Parameter<br/><br/></th>
                    </tr>
```

There is more html below this, but it is just a redundant html form.

UPDATE2:

Well, I never did find a reason why the "if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)" branch is executed directly after an explicit "if(WebSecurity.Login(username, password, false))" branch is executed, however I was able to tie in a separate local boolean variable to the logic and everything is working fine now (I checked to make sure it will always check unless JUST signed in with the branch above, and checked to make sure it does in fact log in, etc.).

If anyone could tell me why this was happening for the benefit of my (and anyone else who comes across this page and has run into a similar problem) education, I will gladly accept the answer.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is  if(WebSecurity.Login(username, password, false)) returning *true* or false?

Comment: It's returning true, because I test and I am logged in after running this code, and there is nothing below this code that could log anyone in. It just keeps re assigning the errorMessage though.

Comment: The lines of code you see are actually the last lines of code in the cshtml file before the html part.

Comment: if you check IsPostBack is true when you come back after login or False

Comment: after resubmitting the credentials, it is a post, yes

Comment: It's ok that login form is post but when it redirect back to this page  then it could be normal post or post back in your case it seems to be post back. then you need to put your above code in if(!IsPostBack){//your code here}

Comment: @sharafjaffri  I can't just blindly use if(!IsPostBack) unless I know what it does.  How does it differ from if(!IsPost)?

Comment: IsPostBack is true if you have posted form and it returns back to same  page without redirect. it's a post which is back to sender page.

Comment: @sharafjaffri Oh, Ok, thanks for that :) I'll remember that in the future if I ever need it.  I hope it works in Razor (autofill doesn't seem to see it while typing if(IsPost) so who knows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember reading on MSDN or someplace, the WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated does not work until the page is fully loaded. Meaning if you login a user in a page and in the same flow of code you check IsAuthenticated, it will NOT return True. For IsAuthenticated to be True the page has to be reloaded or use the better practice; which is to redirect the user to another secured page as soon as the login is successful and in that page check IsAuthenticated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank God someone finally decided to shed some light on this issue for me. It has perplexed me ever since it happened, and while I found a suitable work around, I hate not understanding something I thought I had a firm grasp on. If you can provide a link, Sir, you've got your self an 'upvote' and and 'accept' for your answer.

Comment: I couldn't find any suitable link for your query, but I'll try explaining the scenario to you. WebSecurity works with cookies on your browser, it doesn't set session-based server side variables. Hence once you successfully run a Login and a page is fully dispatched to the user's browser, it contains a cookie which stores that user is logged-in. Next time a page is loaded the browser sends the cookie back to server, by which IsAuthenticated reads that user is logged in. So when Login and IsAuthenticated is called on same page, it doesnt give the server a chance to set the cookie.

Comment: Therefore nothing from WebSecurity will work (CurrentUserName or IsAuthenticated, etc) until the webpage is reloaded after calling Login, i.e. you need to give a chance to the user's webbrowser to resend the cookie to the server by which the server will recognize a logged-in user.

Comment: Well, not only does that make sense, in practice, the behavior of the program on both the client and the server-side are in complete agreement with you. I am going to accept and upvote this answer on the grounds that, in testing, it holds true. Thank you for finally putting this question to rest in my mind!

Answer (score 0):

Check your webconfig, you have to enable forms authentication:

Add following snippet inside

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="3600" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment out if it is in your webconfig:

```
<!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>-->
```

Now you can check

WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId and , WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated flags;